# Toolbar rendering on Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-toolbar, android-appcompat

I used android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar to create a toolbar layout. But the toolbar is show a black text and grey background instead

[image: see screeshot]

Comment: And what is wrong with that? What do you want?

Comment: post your build.gradle file

Comment: click on AppTheme and choose Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar

Answer (score 0):

Add this in styes.xml

```
<style name="Theme.MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
<!-- Set AppCompat's color theming attrs -->
<item name="colorPrimary">@color/my_color</item>
<item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/my_darkercolor</item>
```